# Is this a correct mathematical statement about integers mod n and congruence mod n?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, solution-verification, equivalence-relations

Let's say we have the congruence: $b \equiv a \mod 20$

Is it then correct to say that $(b \equiv a \mod 20 )= \mathbb{Z}_{20}$
where $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ is the set of residue classes or set of equivalence classes of the congruence $b \equiv a \mod 20?$ (So $\mathbb{Z}_{20}=\{{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4], ..., [19]}$}

Comment: I'd write that as $b\equiv a\pmod{20}$. Alas, though your second paragraph makes no sense whatsoever to me.

Comment: $b\equiv a\pmod{20}$ is an assertion that may be true or false, depending on the values of $a$ and $b.$  It doesn't make sense to say this equals $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ which is a different kind of thing altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not proper notation. It seems  you  wish to state that all possible remainders yields a complete set of representatives for $\,\Bbb Z_{20}.\,$ This can be stated (close to your presentation) as follows:

$$\{\, b\in \Bbb Z\ :\ b = (a\bmod 20)\ \ \text{for some } a \in \Bbb Z\} = \Bbb Z_{20}$$

Equivalently, $\ \Bbb Z\bmod 20 = \Bbb Z_{20}\,$ if you define $\bmod$ on sets (but some may object to such notation).

If you wish to work with equivalence (congruence) classes vs. remainders then it is simpler

$$\{ \,[\,a\,]_{20}\ :\ a\in \Bbb Z\} = \Bbb Z_{20}  = \Bbb Z/20\Bbb Z$$

Comment: Doesn't your first off-set line say $\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}_{20}$?

Comment: @Randall  $\  b = a\bmod 20\ $ means $\ b = (a\bmod 20)\ $ not $\ b\equiv a\pmod{20}.\ $ Some writers user $\ b\equiv a\mod 20\ $ for the latter, which, alas, exacerbates such notational confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Saying "$(b \equiv a \mod 20 )= \mathbb{Z}_{20}$" is not correct at all.  At best, the left-hand side would be interpreted as an equivalence class of integers (though not in the way you've written it), which is an *element* of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$.  This would be like taking the true statement $a \in A$ and instead writing $a=A$.  There's a world of difference between $\in$ and $=$.  Maybe this was a typo on your part.

If you you wanted to say that the class of $a$ is a member of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$, acceptable standard notations would be $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_{20}$ or $\overline{a} \in \mathbb{Z}_{20}$.

In short, if $A$ has a relation $\equiv$ on it, you may say that elements $a, b \in A$ are related, written $a \equiv b$.  This is a statement that is either true or false.  You may form equivalence classes, which are *subsets* of $A$:  this would be something like $[a] = \{b \in A \mid a \equiv b\}$.  You may also form the set of these equivalence classes, in which $[a]$ is an element (not a subset) and $a$ is neither element nor subset.

Answer (score 1):

Note that “$b\equiv a\pmod{20}$” is a *proposition*, that can be either true or false, depending on the value of $a$ and $b$. To the contrary, “$\mathbb{Z}_{20}$” is a *set*.

The two objects live in different realms, so they cannot be “equal”; there is a link between the two, because congruence modulo $20$ can be dealt with computations in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$.